# Using maatbitwise export to excel with headings return contains 1 abstract method in laravel

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Somehow I'm using maatbitwise excel to export excel with Laravel but turns out i got the error that i couldn't understand maybe it because `__construct`? here my code on the export class.

```
namespace Module\Registration\Http;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;

class RegistrationExport implements FromCollection, ShouldAutoSize, WithHeadings
{
    public function __construct($collection)
    {
        # code...
        $this->collection = $collection;
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return $this->collection;
    }

    public function heading(): array
    {
        # code...
        return [
            'No',
            'Nama',
            'Nomor Handphone',
            'Email',
            'Tempat Tinggal',
            'Bank',
            'Kartu Kredit',
            'Rumah',
            'Mobil',
            'Keluar Negeri',
            'Penghasilan',
            'Tanggal Daftar'
        ];
    }
}
```

Here my controller, should i use `fromquery` instead of `fromcollection`?
What are causing error and to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forgot the `s` in heading -_- the docs was typo